# HttpErrors Custom Error Page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, web-config, http-error

I am trying to use in a asp.net webforms application custom error pages so i am doing something like this (example the 404 error) :

```
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
     <clear />      
         <error statusCode="404" path="/Pages/Errors/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   </httpErrors>
```

now for the problem, it seems to work half-way, meaning that when a not found page error occurs it is trying to redirect to my Error404.aspx page but resulting in another 404 error because it can't find my custom page . This is INCEPTION!!

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Pages/Errors/Error404.aspx
```

i checked and rechecked my path ,Pages and Errors folders exists, Error404.aspx exists, if i write the path in browser i can access the page , so indeed exists, 
so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the ~ in the path:

```
<error statusCode="404" path="~/Pages/Errors/Error404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
```

another solution is using redirect:

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Pages/Errors/Error404.aspx" />
```